# timemory compiler instrumentation output without symbols

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use [timemory-compiler-instrument](https://timemory.readthedocs.io/en/develop/tools/timemory-compiler-instrument/README.html). I started by following the steps in the documentation and building the `ex_compiler_instrument` example as detailed in the documentation page I linked. Building it as part of `timemory` works as advertised.

I then installed `timemory` and tried to build a similar project, only without basing it on the entire `timemory` build system. I basically took [ex-compiler-instrument](https://github.com/NERSC/timemory/tree/develop/examples/ex-compiler-instrument) and created a new, independent project. The code in the `.cpp` file and the build script are identical, I'm just building them directly instead of going through the `timemory` build process.

This build and runs without problems, but the output does not contain any symbol names:

```
$ cat timemory-compiler-instrumentation-output/wall.txt
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                        REAL-CLOCK TIMER (I.E. WALL-CLOCK TIMER)                                                        |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                            LABEL                             | COUNT  | DEPTH  | METRIC | UNITS  |  SUM   | MEAN   |  MIN   |  MAX   | STDDEV | % SELF |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| >>> [0x559d36ab349c][0x559d36ab439d]                         |      1 |      0 | wall   | sec    |  0.000 |  0.000 |  0.000 |  0.000 |  0.000 |   82.3 |
| >>> |_[0x559d36ab33fd][0x559d36ab34c6]                       |      1 |      1 | wall   | sec    |  0.000 |  0.000 |  0.000 |  0.000 |  0.000 |  100.0 |
| >>> [0x559d36ab331e][0x7f74289ce0b3]                         |      1 |      0 | wall   | sec    |  1.443 |  1.443 |  1.443 |  1.443 |  0.000 |    0.0 |

--- snip ---
```

I assumes this is because I'm missing some compile flags, so I added `-g3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -rdynamic`, my `CMakeLists.txt` now being:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13 FATAL_ERROR)

project(timemory-Compiler-Instrument-Example LANGUAGES CXX)

set(timemory_FIND_COMPONENTS_INTERFACE compiler-instrument-example)
find_package(timemory COMPONENTS compiler-instrument)

if(NOT timemory_FOUND)
    return()
endif()

add_executable(ex_compiler_instrument
    ex_compiler_instrument.cpp)

target_compile_options(ex_compiler_instrument PUBLIC
    -g3
    -fno-omit-frame-pointer
    -fno-optimize-sibling-calls
    -rdynamic)

target_link_libraries(ex_compiler_instrument PRIVATE
    compiler-instrument-example)

install(TARGETS ex_compiler_instrument
    DESTINATION bin
    COMPONENT examples OPTIONAL)
```

Looking at the `timemory` build files there's something similar going on under the hood. In [BuildSettings.cmake](https://github.com/NERSC/timemory/blob/develop/cmake/Modules/BuildSettings.cmake#L271):

```
add_target_flag_if_avail(timemory-compile-debuginfo
    "-g"
    "-fno-omit-frame-pointer"
    "-fno-optimize-sibling-calls")

# --- snip ---

if(TIMEMORY_BUILD_COMPILER_INSTRUMENTATION)
    target_link_libraries(timemory-instrument-functions INTERFACE
        timemory-compile-debuginfo)
endif()
```

However, I'm still missing symbol names in the final output. I'm pretty sure there is something that I'm missing from the setup, but just by looking at the documentation and at the examples I can't figure it out.

I have this problem with both Clang 10 and GCC 9.3. My CMake version is 3.16.3. I'm using timemory 3.2.0.dev4 on Ubuntu 20.04.1.

`nm` displays the symbols:

```
nm --demangle ./ex_compiler_instrument
0000000000005010 V DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0
0000000000004d18 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000004f48 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
000000000000149c t _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
0000000000003000 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U _Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0
00000000000013fd t __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
00000000000018ec W consume(long)
0000000000001851 W fibonacci(long)
00000000000012c9 t __gthread_active_p()

--- snip ---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was figured out by Jonathan R. Madsen on the timemory GitHub repository: I was missing a `-rdynamic` link option:

```
target_link_options(ex_compiler_instrument PRIVATE -rdynamic)
```

Future versions of timemory will `-rdynamic` so this won't be needed anymore, but I'll leave the solution here in case anyone else has this problem and finds this question.